# Launch Minecraft from the command line Python/C++

Tags: c++, python, command-line, minecraft

I have an issue where I am trying to use my previous knowledge of programming to write a Minecraft launcher.  I have use of commands that are in the standard C++ libraries and any Python eggs that are not huge. I would prefer to use `system("java ...")` in order to launch Minecraft.

The question in short:
How do I launch Minecraft from the command line without any auxillary Java code? (Without using launcher code like `net.minecraft.LauncherFrame`) Is it possible? I tried `java -cp mine craft.jar net.minecraft.client.Minecraft` from the Terminal in Mac OS X, to no avail, ending with a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Can anyone shed some light on my problem?
Thank you, 
Pyro.

Comment: Try changing the terminal part to java -jar minecraft.jar net.minecraft.client.Minecraft

Comment: I managed to run minecraft from command line using this: java.exe -cp minecraft.jar;lwjgl.jar;lwjgl_util.jar;jinput.jar ^
-Djava.library.path=natives net.minecraft.client.Minecraft "%INPUT%" --noupdate

Comment: Hmm, neither of those suggestions seem to have worked. I tried both to no avail. It might help to say that I am running a Mac.... Not sure if that is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running on linux, but this also should work for you:

```
java -cp ".minecraft/bin/*" -Djava.library.path=".minecraft/bin/natives/" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft "username" "login id"
```

You don't need to input your username/login id, but if you don't, you can't get in any servers.

You can get your login id here: `https://login.minecraft.net?user=<username>&password=<password>&version=13`

More info about the authentication scheme [here](http://wiki.vg/Legacy_Authentication)

**UPDATE:**
The new launcher for minecraft 1.6 changed a lot.
For the launch command you should look in `.minecraft/versions/<version>/<version>.json`
The authentication also changed. It now uses POST parameters and returns JSON. More about it [here](http://wiki.vg/Authentication).

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. Thank you so much! Where did you find that wiki page, by the way? What did you search?

Comment: I've been interested in the minecraft protocol a while. i searched [this](http://bit.ly/WlzQ6N).

Comment: just for clarification purposes, the `https://login.minecraft.net` returns a string separated into 5 parts by collens (assuming you used the right username and password). the fourth part is the login id.

Comment: you have to run the command `java -cp ...` at your home directory.

Comment: @QxQ The link i added on the post explains everything you just said and changing the paths to the jars is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Like it says above: Look in the file: `.minecraft/versions/<version>/<version>.json` (or [here](http://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.7.4/1.7.4.json)). On that file you can read how minecraft is launched, what libraries it uses, etc... Basically, you need to change the -cp option to point to **Every. Single. Library**, extract the natives manually and change the library path, change `net.minecraft.client.Minecraft` to whatever main class your version is using, and instead of adding the user and password at the end, use the arguments in `minecraftArguments`.