# How do I generate the Minecraft launch command for versions 1.8+ in Python?

Tags: python, authentication, command-line, minecraft, launcher

I am currently working on a little Python project that will function as a custom and highly-configurable launcher for the popular game Minecraft to practice new skills I have been learning recently! However, I am having one problem really throwing me for a loop, and it's just how Minecraft goes about launching the actual game. From my extensive searching, I have learned that the new Minecraft login system sends the user's username and password to authserver.mojang.com/authenticate (the endpoint changing depending on just what is being done) and is returned with an access token, which can be used to log into the game.

(Edit:) What I am asking of you guys is how I would transform the data about where the game is installed and the data received from the POST request into a command that launches the game, alike how it is done in the default launcher. Overnight, I considered looked into the source of the FTB launcher and found [this](https://github.com/Slowpoke101/FTBLaunch/blob/master/src/main/java/net/ftb/minecraft/MCLauncher.java). This is the class for creating this launch command. How could I recreate this in Python?

Note, this question is not a duplicate, the potential duplicates in question are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531917/launch-minecraft-from-command-line-usename-and-password-as-prefix/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617990/launch-minecraft-from-the-command-line-python-c/). Both of these questions are relevant to the old launcher, but the new launcher uses a much different process.

Additionally, I have tried the strategy found [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/156000/launching-minecraft-1-7-4-from-the-command-line/). This does not appear to work correctly on later versions, however. Edit: There was a small detail regarding the natives folder I missed. Basically, if I rename the folder to make a static copy, I can then change the natives directory in the command. However, the command still cannot be generated this way for various users.

If anyone has any ideas about this, feedback is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Alright good news! I figured it out, so I'll post the answer down below as soon as I finish the code.

Comment: Did you ever finish the code?