# Generate OS-specific command to run Minecraft 1.14 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, minecraft, launcher

**Hey guys, I'm working on a flexible Minecraft launcher in Python.**

I have the code for the authentication all sorted out [here](https://github.com/samcarsonx/yggdrasil-py) to get things like the access token to log into the game and all the other necessary bits for a launcher, apart from the most important bit; I haven't got a method to actually start the game.

This isn't a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531917/launch-minecraft-from-command-line-username-and-password-as-prefix) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617990/launch-minecraft-from-the-command-line-python-c/), as they are for the old launcher and system. It could be classed as a duplicate for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38449569/how-do-i-generate-the-minecraft-launch-command-for-versions-1-8-in-python), but that hasn't been answered for a long time.

Basically what I'm asking is, does anybody know how I can start Minecraft from a specific version such as 1.14.4? I'm making this on macOS Mojave but most of my friends who will use it are on Windows 10 so I'll need a method that can work on Windows, macOS and Linux if possible.

*Thanks for any help! -Sam*

Edit: I have it done for the most-part, yet when I start the game I get `Error: Unable to initialize main class net.minecraft.client.main.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: joptsimple/OptionSpec`

Answer (score 0):

Is not so easy  [as you think](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617990/launch-minecraft-from-the-command-line-python-c) :))
You try to make a custom launcher, but minecraft is **Java** (and bedrock edition is **C++**) so you need to have a little knowledge and from thins programming language.
For java you need to know how to work with files from **.jar** (what are just some archives)...
Is **not impossible** but still **not easy**.

Comment: You've linked what I also linked to in the question. It's an outdated system. I've discovered that I can download the natives, game and the command-line arguments from [this page](https://launchermeta.mojang.com/v1/packages/132979c36455cc1e17e5f9cc767b4e13c6947033/1.14.4.json) and I've just managed to get the natives system working.